# What is the easiest way to index (for the search index) 70,000 nodes?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-search

What's the easiest way to index (for the search index) 70.000 nodes in Drupal ?

I'm running cron every 3 minutes (500 nodes per run) but it doesn't seem to be that fast.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that amount of nodes I would go for another search solution, than the one built into drupal core.

Without knowing anything about your content, I would suggest you take a look at Apache Solr for Drupal.

The Drupal Apache Solr module is well tested and maintained.

An added benefit would be better search results than what drupal core search can provide.

Comment: My content is text. Do I need additional server configurations for "Drupal Apache Solr", or I can just install the new module and i'm done ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do manually it by creating php code (in node (**be carefull**)! or in php-file with including bootstrapping), and before running script set maximum time for php."max_execution_time" or use set_time_limit(XXX) in cycle:

```
  $result = db_query('SELECT nid from {node} WHERE /*..HERE IS YOUR CONDITION..*/');
  while ($node = db_fetch_object($result)) {
    _node_index_node($node);
  }
```